# ng-pattern and input text with hebrew unicode letter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a register form inside i want users to insert their first name and last name only in hebrew letters.

this is my ng-pattern:

```
$scope.onlyHebrewPattern = /[\u05D0-\u05F3]+/g;
```

this is my input type:

```
<input type="text" ng-disabled="disableButtons" name="firstname" ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="15" ng-model="register.firstName" placeholder="firstname" ng-pattern="onlyHebrewPattern" required title="please enter your name">
```

then in my controller i go and check:

```
if (!registerForm.firstname.$valid)
```

and if it true i will prompt an error message.

for most cases this will work but there are cases that it won't work for like this input:

לגחדךלכsddski it will not trigger an invalid in the form.

i just can't understand what's wrong. i suppose something with my pattern?

thanks.

Comment: may be because `לגחדךלכsddski` is not "only hebrew"?

Comment: i have edited my question. if i put this input i will not get an $valid error in my form when actually i should get an error

Comment: Here is an answer to a similar question


 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392528/undesirable-result-of-use-of-ng-pattern-angular-js-with-unicode-characters