# ng-pattern for only hebrew characters

Tags: angularjs, regex, hebrew, ng-pattern, angularjs-ng-pattern

I want to use `ng-pattern` validate my text input field that should accept only Hebrew characters, sometimes the input are ok and sometimes they are being rejected for some reason. (the first one is validate the second letter is not and etc.)
example:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" ng-model="Join.firstName" id="firstName" aria-describedby="firstNameHelp" maxlength="15" ng-pattern="onlyHebrewPattern" required>
```

and the solution that given was:
scope.onlyHebrewPattern = /^[\u05D0-\u05F3]+$/g;

[original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392528/undesirable-result-of-use-of-ng-pattern-angular-js-with-unicode-characters)

Comment: Please show an example of rejected string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$scope.onlyHebrewPattern = /^[א-ת\s]+$/;
```