# angularjs ng-pattern for 2 languages

Tags: angularjs, regex

I want to use `ng-pattern` for 2 sets of languages, for example english and hebrew, all my tries just don't work:

```
vm.uNamePattern = "/^[a-zA-Z\s]|[א-ת]*$/";
vm.uNamePattern = "/^[a-zA-Zא-ת\s]*$/";
```

Here is a ref to only hebrew question - [hebrew-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39649726/ng-pattern-for-only-hebrew-characters).

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vm.uNamePattern = "/^[a-zA-Zא-ת\s]*$/";
```

should be

```
vm.uNamePattern = /^[a-zA-Zא-ת\s]*$/;
```

You want a Regexp, not a string.

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/9kWWKhWveqXxsRLV6sXl?p=preview)